# Sorting stored variables in memory

Tags: memory, symbols, clear, storage

Given the list of stored variables

```
Names@"`*"
```

is it possible to sort them by size in used memory?

Comment: I used this in the past : `checkMemory[] :=
 Module[{u}, 
  u = MemoryInUse[]*100/(MemoryInUse[] + MemoryAvailable[]) // N;
  Print["memory used= " <> ToString[u] <> "%"];
  Grid[Reverse@
    SortBy[({ByteCount[ToExpression[#1]]*100/MemoryAvailable[] // N, 
         HoldForm[#1]} &) /@ Names["Global`*"], First]] ]`

Comment: Here's a rough attempt to sort by the size of the `OwnValues`, i.e. to differentiate true "variable" symbols not symbols that auto evaluate: ```SortBy[Names["`*"], ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Function[Null, ByteCount[HoldComplete[#] /. OwnValues[#]], HoldAllComplete]]```

Comment: `SortBy[Names@"\`*", ByteCount@ToExpression@# &]`